# MySql: How to "list" records with equal text in a column

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with text and want to get all records which have the same text, like:

```
SELECT t1.id, t2.id FROM table AS t1
    LEFT JOIN table AS t2 ON (t1.txt = t2.txt AND t1.id != t2.id);
```

This works fine so far. The problem is that a text might occure more than twice. In the statement above, I get (if id 1, 2 and 3 have the same txt):

```
1    2
1    3
2    1
2    3
3    1
3    2
```

It would be greate to get something like:

```
1    2|3
2    1|3
3    1|2
```

Best would be to get no doubles, but I guess if it's possible it might be a very slow query:

```
1    2|3
```

Any idea how to achieve this directly in mysql?

Comment: Can you provide sample data and your desired results based on that data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get your desired results using `GROUP BY` and `GROUP_CONCAT()`:

```
SELECT t1.id, GROUP_CONCAT(t2.id SEPARATOR '|')
FROM table t1 LEFT JOIN
     table t2
     ON t1.txt = t2.txt AND t1.id <> t2.id
GROUP BY t1.id;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can get the first expected output using `group_concat`:

```
select t1.id,
    group_concat(t2.id separator '|')
from table as t1
left join table as t2 on (
        t1.txt = t2.txt
        and t1.id != t2.id
        )
group by t1.id;
```